# Is there any obvious relation between sodium bicarbonate and ammonia; (how) can sodium bicarbonate be involved in producing ammonia?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, chemical-biology

Using sodium bicarbonate as a deodorant sometimes can produce a strong ammonia smell. Is there some obvious chemical explanation for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ammonia is present in variable amounts in perspiration, especially after exercise, but since the pH of perspiration is usually acidic (4.5 - 7), the amount of free NH3 is small. Adding NaHCO3 can raise the pH to 8.5 and  free up NH3 from its ammonium (NH4+) ion.